# How do I fix this NoClassDefFoundError in intellij?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run my program but I keep getting an error that says

**Error:scalac: Error: scala/annotation/varargs
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/annotation/varargs**

There are no error lines in the code but every time I run the program this error appears. I'm trying to run the code that my professor provided to us. It seems as if I'm the only one having a problem getting it to run.  I have had this problem with some other Intellij projects that I've been working on. My project SDK is java 1.8 and I'm using the scala-sdk-2.12.10. My scala is version 2019.3.23. Please tell me if this is not enough information to help. I'm new to programming so I'm not quite familiar with everything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try with previous versions with Scala. Later versions of Scala may not contain the classes that you need. To elaborate more you need to provide the code snippet where this error is throwing